# Django signal does perform action on last created record

Tags: python, django, celery, django-signals

I have two django signals that on creation kick off some actions. The **order_fully_paid_signal** kicks off **save_to_db** to the **PrinterReceivedInfo** model. When that model record is created it writes the file to Azure file storage (which is a celery task under tasks.py).

The task is just basically taking all the output of a database table and writing it to a text file in Azure. **It writes all the data except the last record that has been created by the signal.**

I suspect I have misunderstood the way that the **.delay** is working. Any help is really appreciated.

Signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def order_fully_paid_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.get_payment_status() == "fully-charged":
        #some action
        save_to_db = PrinterReceivedInfo.objects.create(order_id=order_id, order_string=order)

@receiver(post_save, sender=PrinterReceivedInfo)
def azure_method(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    save_to_azure.delay()
```

tasks.py

```
@app.task
def save_to_azure():
    
    config_variables = ConfigurationSettings.objects.get(pk=1)
    azure_container_name = config_variables.config_azure_container_name
    azure_blob_name = config_variables.config_azure_blob_name
    azure_account_key = config_variables.config_azure_account_key

    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=azure_container_name, account_key=azure_account_key)

    #Get a list of unprocessed orders (not sent to the receipt printer)
    unprocessed_orders = PrinterReceivedInfo.objects.filter(printer_description="Pending")

    #For each unprocessed order, recreate a new text file
    blob_content = ""
    for item in unprocessed_orders:
        blob_content += item.order_string + "\n"
    
    #Write the file back to Azure. If the file does not exist, it will be created
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text(azure_container_name, azure_blob_name, blob_content, content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='text/plain'))
```

Comment: Is `"Pending"` the default value for `printer_description`? Also, can you show the code that creates the initial `Order` instance? Is it part of a view action that's atomic for instance?

Comment: I'm not sure but the actual instance record is not processed, so I have to pass it in manually, e.g. blob_content += item.order_string + instance_order_string. I have to pass in the instance aswell